# `gulp-postcss is not a function` type error when it provided by gulp-load-plugins

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, gulp, postcss

I make some kind of mistake when extended TypeScirpt interface `IGulpPlugins` from type definitions for [gulp-load-plugins](https://www.nxworld.net/services-resource/gulp-plugin-gulp-load-plugins.html), or incorrectly defined types of [gulp-postcss](https://github.com/postcss/gulp-postcss).

According comment in `index.d.ts` of [@types/gulp-load-plugins](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/gulp-load-plugins/index.d.ts):

```
/**
 * Extend this interface to use Gulp plugins in your gulpfile.js
 */
interface IGulpPlugins {
}
```

All of below plugins except `gulp-postcss` works.

```js
import * as gulpDebug from 'gulp-debug';
import * as gulpPlumber from 'gulp-plumber';
import * as gulpIntercept from 'gulp-intercept';
import * as gulpIf from 'gulp-if';
import * as gulpPug from 'gulp-pug';
import * aas gulpHtmlPrettify from 'gulp-html-prettify';
import * as gulpSass from 'gulp-sass';
import * as gulpStylus from 'gulp-stylus';
import * as gulpSourcemaps from 'gulp-sourcemaps';
import * as gulpPostCss from 'gulp-postcss';

export interface IGulpPlugins {
  plumber: typeof gulpPlumber;
  debug: typeof gulpDebug;
  intercept: typeof gulpIntercept;
  if: typeof gulpIf;
  pug: typeof gulpPug;
  htmlPrettify: typeof gulpHtmlPrettify;
  sass: typeof gulpSass;
  stylus: typeof gulpStylus;
  postCss: typeof gulpPostCss;
  sourcemaps: typeof gulpSourcemaps;
}
```

The are no TypseScript compiling errors in below code, however if to execute compiled TypeScript, `TypeError: gulpPlugins.postCss is not a function` error will occurs.

```js
import * as gulp from 'gulp';
import * as GulpPlugins from 'gulp-load-plugins';

// I did not create types for this libary yet, so temporary make TypeScript to ignore it
// @ts-ignore
import * as postcssNormalizeWhitespace from 'postcss-normalize-whitespace';

gulpPlugins: IGulpPlugins = GulpPlugins();

return gulp.src(SOURCE_FILES_GLOB_SELECTION)
    .pipe(gulpPlugins.postCss([postcssNormalizeWhitespace]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
```

If to write

```js
import * as gulp from 'gulp';
import * as GulpPlugins from 'gulp-load-plugins';

/* When I wrote this question, types in DefinitelyTyped for this library was not exists yet,
 * but I created it. However did not create the pull request yet.
 */
import * as gulpPostCss from 'gulp-postcss';

// I did not create types for this libary yet, so temporary make typescript ingore it
// @ts-ignore
import * as postcssNormalizeWhitespace from 'postcss-normalize-whitespace';


return gulp.src(SOURCE_FILES_GLOB_SELECTION)
    .pipe(gulpPostCss([postcssNormalizeWhitespace]))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));
```

instead, JavaScript will work without errors.

I can not understand, where I did mistake. 
Let me repeat that all plugins in extended IGulpPlugins except `gulp-postcss` works.

The types for `gulp-postcss` that I wrote are:

```js
/// <reference types="node"/>
import Vinyl = require('vinyl');

declare function GulpPostCss(plugins?: Array<string>, options?: GulpPostCss.Options): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream;
declare function GulpPostCss(callback?: (file: Vinyl) => { plugins?: Array<string>, options?: GulpPostCss.Options }): NodeJS.ReadWriteStream;

declare namespace GulpPostCss {
    interface Options {
        parser?: string;
    }
}

export = GulpPostCss;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things you didn't get right.

1. You made a typo, or maybe don't understand how `gulp-load-plugins` works.

If your plugin name is `gulp-post-css`, then it becomes `gulpPlugins.postCss`. However, that plugin name is `gulp-postcss`, so it will be:

```
gulpPlugins.postcss(...) // NOT gulpPlugins.postCss !!!
```

2. You don't understand typescript.

This has nothing to do with typescript.

Here's a rule of thumb: typescript has **zero** impact on javascript runtime behaviour. Whenever you find a runtime error, it must come from the javascript side of typescript.

Though 1. has already solved your problem, let's pretend you MUST use `gulpPlugins.postCss`. In order for this to work, try add these lines:

```
import * as gulpPostCss from 'gulp-postcss';
gulpPlugins.postCss = gulpPostCss;
```

Now it'll work.

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank your for explanations.